# Calling .exe in PHP and want to display result On a web based GUI

Tags: php

I have combinely used PHP and HTML for this. But I want only 500 records to be displayed on one page.The problem is when i set page 1 manually in code it works but when i click on some page the entire data is not submitted as the form is written in HTML above PHP. So i cannot hold the webpage for taking the entire form data for page 2.

Here is the code for index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Project  </title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendarDateInput.js"></script>

</head>
<body>    
<div>           
    <h1 align=center>Project</h1>
</div>
<form action="index.php" method="post">

<h3>Select options</h3>
<select name="options" >
<option value="(NULL)">select</option>
<option value="-import">Import</option>
<option value="-view">View</option>
<option value="-clean">Clean</option>
<option value="-help">Help</option>
</select> 


<h3> Enter component  
<input type="text" name="component"  />
<h3>Enter <script type="text/javascript" src="calendarDateInput.js"></script>
<script>DateInput('orderdate', true, 'YYYY-MM-DD')</script> to
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendarDateInput.js"></script>
<script>DateInput('orderdate1', true, 'YYYY-MM-DD')</script> Date 

<h3>Enter Severity
<select name="severity">
<option value="(NULL)">select</option>
<option value="INFO">Info</option>
<option value="WARNING">Warning</option>
<option value="ERROR">Error</option>
</select> 
</h3>

<!--<h3>Enter Records per page
<select name="records">
<option value="(NULL)">select</option>
<option value='"0 to 100"'>100</option>
<option value='"0 to 500"'>500</option>
<option value='"0 to 1000"'>1000</option>
</select> 
</h3>-->

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" /> 


</form>


<?php

include ('pagination.php'); 

$arg=$_POST['options'];

$arg1=" -component ";
$arg1.=$_POST['component'];

$arg2=" -date ";
$arg2.='"';
$arg2.=$_POST['orderdate'];

$arg3=" to ";
$arg3.=$_POST['orderdate1'];
$arg3.='"';

$arg4=" -severity ";
$arg4.=$_POST['severity'];





$command= "\"E:\\CLV\\x64\\Release\\project.exe\" ";
$command.=$arg;



if(strcmp($arg,"-view")==0)
{
    $command.=$arg1;
    $command.=$arg2;
    $command.=$arg3;
    $command.=$arg4;
    $command.=$arg5;
}
echo "<pre>";
echo $command;
echo "</pre>";

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$output=shell_exec($command);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";


?>
```

here is the code for pagination.php

```
<?php

/* Set current, prev and next page */
$page = (!isset($_GET['page']))? 1 : $_GET['page']; 
$prev = ($page - 1);
$next = ($page + 1);

/* Max results per page */
$max_results = 500;

/* Calculate the offset */
$from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);


$total_pages = 13;

$pagination = '';

/* Create a PREV link if there is one */
if($page > 1)
{
   $pagination.=" ";
   $pagination .= '<a href="?page='.$prev.'">Previous</a> ';
$pagination.=" ";
}

/* Loop through the total pages */
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{
    if(($page) == $i)
     {

            $pagination .= $i;
    $pagination.=" ";
    $arg5=" -record ";
    $arg5.='" ';
    $arg5.= $from;
    $arg5.=" - ";
    $arg5.=$page * $max_results; 
    $arg5.=' "';
    }
    else
    {
    $pagination.=" ";
        $pagination .= '<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    $pagination.=" ";

     }
 }

/* Print NEXT link if there is one */
if($page < $total_pages)
{
  $pagination.=" ";
  $pagination .= '<a href="?page='.$next.'">Next</a>';
  $pagination.=" ";
 }

echo $pagination;
?>
```

Comment: Is this going to be an Internet-accessible website?  That's some very dangerous code with potential script-injection flaws.

Comment: No not internet accessible. We will run it on http:localhost:8000.